# IOI 2003 : how to calculate the node that has the minimum balance in a tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

here is the [Balancing Act](http://www.ioinformatics.org/locations/ioi03/contest/day0/balance.pdf) problem that demands to find the node that has the minimum balance in a tree. Balance is defined as :

> Deleting any node
>   from the tree yields a **forest** : a collection of one or more trees. Define the **balance** of a node to be the size of the largest tree in the forest T created by deleting that node from T

For the sample tree like :

> 2 6 
> 1 2 
> 1 4 
> 4 5
>  3 7
>  3 1

Explanation is :

> Deleting node 4 yields two trees whose member nodes are {5} and {1,2,3,6,7}. The
>   larger of these two trees has five nodes, thus the balance of node 4 is five. Deleting node
>   1 yields a forest of three trees of equal size: {2,6}, {3,7}, and {4,5}. Each of these trees
>   has two nodes, so the balance of node 1 is two.

What kind of algorithm can you offer to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Homework ? ... Is this just a general tree ? or can you make your own kind of tree ?

Comment: @yochai it is not homework. I'm not a student and just want to solve this. Tree is given just like input from x -> y

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you have had a looong look at this problem: reading the solution does not help, you only get better at solving these problems by solving them *yourself*.

So one thing to observe is, the input is a tree. That means that each edge joins 2 smaller trees together. Removing an edge yields 2 disconnected trees (a forest of 2 trees).

So, if you calculate the size of the tree on one side of the edge, and then on the other, you should be able to look at a node's edges and ask "What is the size of the tree on the other side of this edge?"

You can calculate the sizes of trees using dynamic programming - your recurrence state is "What edge am I on? What side of the edge am I on?" and it calculates the size of the tree "hung" at that node. That is the crux of the problem.

Having that data, it is sufficient to iterate through all the nodes, look at their edges and ask "What is the size of the tree on the other side of this edge?" From there, you just pick the minimum.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to check 3 things for every node:

1. The size of its left subtree.
2. The size of its right subtree.
3. The size of the rest of the tree. (size of tree - left - right)

You can use this algorithm and expand it to any kind of tree (different number of subnodes).

Go over the tree in an [in-order sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Traversal).

Do this recursively:

Every time you just before you back up from a node to the "father" node, you need to add 1+size of node's total sub trees, to the "father" node.
Then store a value, let's call it **maxTree**, in the node that holds the maximum between all its subtrees, and the (sum of all subtrees)-(size of tree).

This way you can calculate all the subtree sizes in ***O(N)***.
While traversing the tree, you can hold a variable that hold the minimum value found so far.